# ICMP destination Unreachable packet rate limit

Tags: ubuntu

What is the ICMP Destination Unreachable packet rate limit of the
OS? How to find this from Linux?

Could I change this rate limit? How?

I am currently working on Ubuntu and Windows. I run Ubuntu inside an Oracle VirtualBox VM, which is running on Windows.

Comment: Yes I am running ubuntu on Windows 10 through Oracle Virtual box

Comment: Thank you. I have used the "edit" function to put this information in your question. If you don't like how I wrote it, you can also edit it yourself :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Linux this variable is stored in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit`. You can query that value with either `sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit` or `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit`.

To change the limit, to 10 for example, you can either do `sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit=10` or `echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit`.

Note, you do need to use `sudo` to use `sysctl` and to set the ratelimit.

Comment: assuming that `icmp_ratemask` includes host unreachable. otherwise it would be unlimited, right?

Comment: @sourcejedi that is a good question, I am not sure about it but I find it reasonable to assume unlimited as you do.

Comment: pleasingly, it looks like  there is no ratelimit on icmp errors returned over loopback.   also the ratelimit looks to be per ipv4 peer address. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/net/ipv4/icmp.c#L311  I'm not certain if ipv6 is doing the same https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/net/ipv6/icmp.c#L194